# Windows Server 2008 R2 as time source

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ntp

I use Windows Server 2008 R2 as server for few hundreds devices (Android OS) which has allowed access only to this server and denied to any other IP. Because these devices aren't able to remember time when they are unplugged (time is reset to 1 Jan 2011) I want my server to be source of time (like NTP server) for these devices.
When I used google I've found something about w32time service but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.
Question is simple - how can I do this service for my devices?

Comment: How are your devices expecting to get the time ? do they support standard ntp? Also where does your Windows box get its time from & is it part of a domain or a standalone server which the devices are allowed to access?

Answer (score 0):

To allow a Tablet PC, used as Terminal of a web server embbeded in a non-screen/non-keyboard, to keep time and date, I have used the w32time Windows Service. When well-configured, this service convert the Windows computer to a NTP Server and, even if the Tablet PC is not a high quality time source, the embbeded web server stays on time.

1- Stop the w32time Service
from cmd.exe as administrator execute:

```
net stop w32time
```

2- Modify the registry 
from regedit.exe set the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\
....NtpServer\Enabled = 1
```

3- Start the w32time Service
from cmd.exe as administrator execute:

```
net start w32time
```

Your Windows Server is ready to be SNTP.
And your Android devices could become NTP Client by using a dedicated app.

You can take a look of the blog '[How to Setup a Windows 2008 R2 SNTP/NTP Server](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2009/12/21/how-to-setup-a-windows-2008-r2-sntp-ntp-server.aspx)'.